Django and railway, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mainApp.wsgi'
I deployed my project on railway from GitHub. I searched the internet for a solution, but I can't figure out what the proble is.
link @GitHub https://github.com/DanielThisShouldWork/Dead_Calculator
This is my Procfile:
web: gunicorn mainApp.wsgi --log-file -

This is the path at my wsgi:
Desktop\\Project_countdown\\mainApp\\mainApp\\wsgi.py

So I tried:
web: gunicorn mainApp/mainApp.wsgi --log-file -
web: gunicorn mainApp/wsgi --log-file -
web: gunicorn mainApp/mainApp/wsgi --log-file -
web: gunicorn mainApp.wsgi:application --log-file -

I don't know if the problem is here, or maybe in something in setting.py. Even if railway should go by himself with DATABASE_URL.
My Procfile should be in the root, so should be ok:
Desktop\\Project_countdown\\Procfile

Thre requirements are ok.
This is my setting.py:
from pathlib import Path
import os
import dj_database_url
from dj_database_url import parse as dburl


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-j3fa@o20ztumez^!y9wq78)@nf&tr9a(21v7+u8(x*0!yfg0hp'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', 'False') == 'True'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

#DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://postgres:qsEbkuuosxNigTWTuawotSBFnioLbncN@postgres.railway.internal:5432/railway'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mainApp',
    'application',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mainApp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mainApp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
}



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


"This is the path at my wsgi: Desktop\Project_countdown\mainApp\mainApp\wsgi.py"—where is your root project directory in this hierarchy? (I.e., where's the .git/ directory?)

@Chris im working on a virtual env, so i think i dont have a .git/ directory in my project folder (?). The root should be /Project_countdown.

Ok, fixed it. Don't ask me how, i just removed my venv folder from the project and all good...
